# Common protocol for UIViewcontroller and UITableviewcontroller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I was writting some common methods to show alert loader like things,

I wanted those methods to be accessed from uiviewcontroller and uitableviewcontroller subclasses,

How can we achive the same?

Answer (score 3):

Create `UIViewController` extension and add your alert method like shown below.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showAlert(title: String, message: String, buttonName: String, alertActionHandler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil) {

        guard let alertActionHandler = alertActionHandler else {
            return
        }

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let actionButton = UIAlertAction(title: buttonName, style: .default, handler: { action in
            alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            alertActionHandler(action)
        })
        alertController.addAction(actionButton)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And you can call `showAlert` method anywhere in your viewcontrollers.

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, you can create an extension of `UIViewController` and functions declared there can be accessed by instances of both:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create NSObject type common file like see the following code. and then you can call from `UIViewController` or `UITableviewController` or from any file/controller.

```
import UIKit

class AppUtils: NSObject {

    static func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(ok)
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Call showAlert function:-

```
AppUtils.showAlert(title: "My Title", message: "My Message")
```

Comment: Why would `AppUtils` need to be a subclass of `NSObject`? That's completely unnecessary...

Comment: Hi @devidPasztor if you create extension of UIViewController then you can not call everywhere like from UIView class, if you are used any XIB and UIView then your not able to call this method from UIView class, But if you create AppUtil class from  NSObject then you can use this function from everywhere, So this is the best way to solve this issue.

Comment: OP wanted to call this method from all **view controllers**, so there's no need to make it available from a `UIView`. Moreover, making your class inherit from `NSObject` doesn't change its visibility at all, you could achieve the same without the inheritance.

Comment: Okay thanks for this information,But if we want to call a common function like this showAlert from UIview or UIViewController or UITableviewController then what we need to do? How can we solve this?, I don't want to create more than one common function, Please suggest me.

Comment: @AtulParmar see my solution

Comment: @ArashEtemad in which file need to write this method?

Comment: you can create a blank swift file and name it like `GlobalViewFunctions` or whatever an put this method on it

Comment: in your code has an error "Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'present'"

Comment: Also, get an error like:- Use of 'showAlert' nearly matches global function 'showAlert(_:title:message:)' in module 'projectname

Answer (score 1):

You can write a global method in this way:

```
func showAlert(_ view: UIView, title: String, message: String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
            switch action.style{
                case .default:
                    print("default")

                case .cancel:
                    print("cancel")

                case .destructive:
                    print("destructive")

            }}))

        view.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And use it in every ViewController:

```
 showAlert(self.view, title: Alert, message: "Hi")
```

Comment: If you want a method to be accessible from all view controllers, you can simply extend `UIViewController`, there's no need to declare a global function.